# Concatenating strings from multiple lines in a file separated by newlines

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a file with multiple lines like:

```
name1  
12345  
67890

name2  
23456  
78901

name3  
34567  
89012
```

How would I go about concatenating each line in the form:

```
"name1 1234567890"

"name2 2345678901"

"name3 3456789012"
```

Specifically, what is the best way to concatenate strings from a file into a single line until an empty line is encountered?

Comment: What have you already tried?
Have you tried solving the problem at all?

Comment: Do name1, name2, etc., have spaces after them in the file, or do you need to add a space only after the first item in each group? Will there always be two additional rows in each group? (Most of the solutions below assume the items always come in groups of 3 rows and need a space added after the first row.)

Answer (score 1):

You can split first with `\n\n` and then split `\n` to get each item.

```
data = open('file_name').read()

output = ["%s %s%s" % tuple(item.split('\n')) for item in data.split('\n\n')]
```

> ['name1 1234567890', 'name2 2345678901', 'name3 3456789012']

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input file is called `file_input` and your output file is called `file_output`, you can do something like this:

```
# Read your input file, removing \n and spliting by spaces
with open("input_file", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read().rstrip().split()

# Opening a new file in append mode 'a' 
with open("output_file", 'a') as f:
    # Processing your data by iterating through the data list with steps
    n = ['"{0} {1}"'.format(k, "".join(v)) for k,*v in zip(data[::3], data[1::3], data[2::3])]
    for k in n:
        f.write(k+"\n")
```

Output:

```
"name1 1234567890"
"name2 2345678901"
"name3 3456789012"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way that doesn't read the entire file into memory at once. I also don't assume that there are only 3 lines in each group.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> with open("fin") as fin:
...     groups = groupby(fin, str.isspace)
...     for name, *rest in (map(str.strip, v) for  g,v in groups if not g):
...         print(name, " ", *rest, sep="")
... 
name1 1234567890
name2 2345678901
name3 3456789012
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done with just `split`.

```
for x in open('the_file', 'r').read().split('\n\n'): # split the file on empty lines
    m = x.split() # split on line break
    print '"{} {}{}"\n'.format(m[0], m[1], m[2])
```

**Output**:

```
"name1 1234567890"

"name2 2345678901"

"name3 3456789012"
```